# Efficient python way for recursive equations

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

I am trying to optimize a Loop that I have in a piece of my code. I thought that writing it in a more numpy way would make it faster, but is slower now!
the equations takes as input a numpy.array vec of length n:

```
from numpy import *

def f(vec):
    n=len(vec)
    aux=0
    for i in range(n):
        aux = aux + (1- aux)*vec[i]
    return aux

def f2(vec):
    n=len(vec)
    G=tril(array([-vec]*n),-1)+1              #numpy way!
    aux=dot(G.prod(1),vec)
    return aux


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("f(ones(225)+4)", setup="from __main__ import f\nfrom numpy import ones",number=1000))
    print(timeit.timeit("f2(ones(225)+4)", setup="from __main__ import f2\nfrom numpy import ones,tril,dot",number=1000))
```

0.429496049881 [s]

5.66514706612  [s]

Finally I decided to inserte the whole function in my loop, getting a 3x performance boost. I am really looking for a 100x performance boost, but dont know what else to do. This is my final function:

```
def CALC_PROB_LOC2(int nSectors, int nZones,double[:] beta, double[:] thetaLoc,np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] h, np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] p, np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=3] U_nij, np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] A_ni):
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=3] Pr_nij  =np.zeros((nSectors,nZones,nZones),dtype="d")
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] U_ni    =np.zeros((nSectors,nZones),dtype="d")
    #cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] A_ni_pos
    cdef Py_ssize_t n,i,opt
    cdef int aux_bool,options
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] prob,attractor,optionCosts
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] eq23,utilities
    cdef double disu
    cdef double eq22
    cdef double aux17
    for n in range(nSectors):
        aux_bool=1
        if n in [0,2,9,10,11,12,13,14,18,19,20]:
            for i in xrange(nZones):
                U_ni[n,i]=p[n,i]+h[n,i]
                Pr_nij[n,i,i]=1
            aux_bool=0
        if aux_bool==1:
            if beta[n]<=0:
                for i in xrange(nZones):
                    U_ni[n,i]=U_nij[n,i,i]
            else:
                A_ni_pos=A_ni[n,:]>0
                options=len(A_ni[n,:][A_ni_pos])
                attractor=A_ni[n,:][A_ni_pos]
                if options>0:
                    for i in xrange(nZones):
                        optionCosts=U_nij[n,i,A_ni_pos]
                        disu=0
                        eq22=0
                        aux17=0
                        prob=np.ones(options)/options #default value
                        if beta[n]==0:
                            Pr_nij[n,i,A_ni_pos],U_ni[n,i]= prob,0
                        if options==1:
                            Pr_nij[n,i,A_ni_pos],U_ni[n,i]= prob,optionCosts
                        else:
                            if thetaLoc[n]<=0:
                                cmin=1
                            else:
                                cmin=(optionCosts**thetaLoc[n]).min()
                                if cmin==0:
                                    cmin=100
                            utilities=optionCosts/cmin
                            eq23=-beta[n]*utilities
                            eq23=np.exp(eq23)
                            aux17=np.dot(attractor,eq23)
                            if aux17==0:
                                Pr_nij[n,i,A_ni_pos],U_ni[n,i]= 0*prob,0
                            else:
                                for opt in range(options):
                                    eq22=eq22+(1-eq22)*eq23[opt]
                                prob=attractor*eq23/aux17
                                disu=cmin*(-np.log(eq22)/beta[n])
                                Pr_nij[n,i,A_ni_pos],U_ni[n,i]= prob,disu


    return Pr_nij,U_ni
```

Comment: What is `vec`? and what is `n`?

Comment: the equations takes as input a numpy array vec of length n:

Comment: How did you determine it runs slower? If you timed it, post your test and results.

Comment: Then how did you know it was slower if you didn't [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)?

Comment: I ahve a part of my code that calls the method 8000 times, and I got different timings with both methods.

Comment: @tcapelle if you are using ipython just do `timeit function_to_run`

Comment: How do you get those different timings? Have you timed it to be slower on the same dataset? Or does it *seem* slower?

Comment: numpy will speed up things when they can be vectorized. This means that the loop will be removed and you calculate the whole `aux` vector in parallel. For this to happen, you need to be able to calculate `aux[i]` directly. In your case, you need `aux[i-1]` to calculate `aux[i]` so you cannot vectorize the solution, as far as I can see. I think you have two options: Either use Cython or find a closed-form mathematical solution to this recursion equation.

Comment: @tcapelle: Unrelated to your question: I would suggest that you read the [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), so that your coding style matches the usual coding style. This will make your programs more legible for everybody (including you!).

Comment: On top of what @EOL said (it can't be stressed enough), checkout "docstrings", keep one question per post, and finally the function `logit2` that you've just added will hardly be sped up by cython (which is good for loops, calling compiled libraries, wrapping them... but doesn't make much sense when you're simply calling numpy function on whole arrays).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's what happens when a linear algorithms gets replaced by a quadratic one: No matter how fast it's executed, the better algorithm always wins (for a problem big enough).

It's pretty clear that `f` runs in linear time, and `f2` runs in quadractic time because that's the time complexity of a matrix-vector dot product.

A log-log plot clearly shows the difference in running time (linear refers to `f`, quadractic to `f2`):

[image: Two algorithms compared]

The right-most part of the green line (ie, when it doesn't behave as a straight line) can be explained because numpy functions usually have a high overhead that's negligible for arrays that are not tiny but dominates the running time when they are small.

---

The "standard" way to speed up code in Python that's already using a fast algorithm is to reach for compiled code and write an extension. [Cython](http://cython.org/) lets you do that by annotating the Python source code with a few type annotations, and it understands numpy arrays.

By telling Cython that `vec` is an array of doubles, `aux` is a double and `i` an integer, it's able to generate a C extension which is 400x faster for me.

```
def f(double[:] vec):
    n = len(vec)
    cdef double aux = 0
    cdef int i
    for i in range(n):
        aux = aux + (1- aux)*vec[i]
    return aux
```

If you happen to be using [IPython](http://ipython.org/), you can just run `%load_ext cythonmagic` and then copy that function to a cell prefixed by the line `%%cython` to try it out. Other methods to build and compile it are explained in the Cython [documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html). By the way, IPython also lets you timeit code by writing `%timeit` before the statement to time, it's really handy.

A completely different option is to use [PyPy](http://pypy.org/), a Python 2.7 implementation that comes with a JIT and has some basic numpy support. It can run this small snippet by replacing `import numpypy` for `import numpy`, but it's possible that it won't be able to run your whole program. It is a tad slower than Cython but it doesn't requiere a compiler nor annotating the code.

Comment: @tcapelle Are you interested in ways to make it faster? I didn't say anything about that! One option is running it in pypy (using numpypy instead of numpy). Another one is to use Cython and typedef `i` and `aux`.

Comment: help me with that please, I call this function like a zillion of times

Comment: Great answer!!! I did the workaround with cython, and I dont get that much speed =(. the problem is that I call this function many times (around 10000 times) but for a rater small size of vec (225). I use a Pool.map for the callings.

Comment: @tcapelle For that size, it's 140x faster in my laptop. Maybe we can help you a bit more if you add more details on how you're calling it to the question?

Comment: OK, I will be back on Tuesday. I will explain more details then.

Comment: Ok, It worked so well that now I am going to try to re-write a bigger function on cython. But I run into problems deffining auxiliar arrays inside loops (as I do on numpy) Can I do that? or arrays have to be of fixed size?

Comment: @tcapelle I'm sorry but I don't really follow you. What do you mean? Can you post a code snippet somewhere? The size of numpy arrays can't be modified inplace efficiently (unlike Python lists).

Comment: The Cython profiler tells me that, the numpy.min, mean and zeros are expensive time.

Comment: The annotated code shows how much Python vs pure C is there. So, yellow inside a loop isn't great because it has to go back to the python interpreter. But if you're calling `np.min`, etc outside loops or for big arrays the calling overhead won't matter (as those functions are already optimised).

Comment: You have been very helpful my friend!

Comment: To give you and idea, my function takes 0.2 [s], and I need to omptimize a vector of 10.000, so for just one evaluation it takes 2000 [s].

Comment: @tcapelle I can just point you to the [Cython tutorial on profiling](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/profiling_tutorial.html). I hope it helps. This has been a nice question! And sorry to sound repetitive, but using a consistent code style in Python really helps its readability: try to follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It's a must if you want to get your code in almost any Python project, and it helps anybody reading your code.